# Setting the default datatype of LINQ to sql datacontext

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Is there any way of changing the default mapping for LINQ to sql datacontexts? I want to change `INT` to map to `long` rather than `int` every time a new entity is created.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? T-SQL `INT` is 32-bit, just like C# `int`.

Comment: @svick Im talking to a suppliers webservice that uses long. It saves casting and means I can save code by using reflection if they are the same datatype

Comment: why not just use long in your DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways I can think of:

1. Create a DBML file.
2. Find-replace `System.Int32` to `System.Int64` (easy to create a little command-line app so you just need to double-click it whenever you refresh the DBML).
3. Use the DBML file.

Or:

Just hand-code the classes anyway. I actually find it handier to hand-code than DBML - when I make a change I'm likely going to be making a bunch of related changes anyway, so it fits right into how I'm thinking of the change's implications anyway.